# Divergence of a Function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

I need to find the divergence of $f^2(x)x$, where I assume that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I have been given the solution, I just cannot remember how to complete this calculation:
[image]
I know that one takes the divergence of a vector field. Does this mean that $f^2(x)x$ is a vector field for which every component is of the form $f^2(x_i)x_i$. For exmaple, if $n=2$, would we have  the vector field $F(x,y) = (f^2(x)x,f^2(y)y)$?

Also, how does one calculate this - I tried to calculate the derivative with respect to each component $x_i$ and then sum over $n$:

$$
\partial_{x_i} = 2f(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial_{x_i}} x + f^2(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial_{x_i}}
$$

Then summing over all derivatives gives:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n 2f(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial_{x_i}} x + \sum_{i=1}^nf^2(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial_{x_i}} = 2f(x) x \nabla x + f^2(x) \nabla x
$$

However, this is clearly wrong.

Comment: The derivative of $f^2(x)$ should be $2f(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)$ which explains your mistake.

Comment: @Pedro thank you. So then I get the correct first term. But for the second term why is it $nf^2(x)$ instead of $f^2(x) \nabla x$?

Comment: You confuse the notations, so it leads to wrong computation. The component is $x_i,$ and when computing the derivative w.r.t to $x_i,$ i.e. $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_i} = 1.$

Comment: @Pedro Would you mind clarifying the notation. If this $x$ should actually be $x_i$, how come the $x$ inside of $f^2(x)$ is not $x_i$ aswell? Im just not really sure what vector field $f^2(x)x$ describes.

Comment: the $x$ in $f^2(x)$ is an argument, it doesnt concern the component $x_i.$ To compute the divergence, you have to know exactly what the component is. Here, the component of $f^2(x)x$ is $f^2(x)x_i$ for $x_i$ coordinates of the vector $x.$

Comment: @Pedro ah ok so in the expression $xf^2(x)$, the two $x$'s do not refer to the same thing. Could you please explain why that is / how you know that? Thanks

Comment: mainly by practice and by experience :D mistakes are normal in mathematics.

Comment: @Pedro How come the same $x$ variable is used in different ways in the same expression?

Comment: There are two roles of $x$ in your expression. The x in $f(x)$ is an argument, and the $x$ in vector $x$ is a value. For a function, $y = f(x),$ $y$ is the value of $f$ at the argument $x.$ Maybe it is clear?

Answer (score 1):

Denote the vector
$\mathbf{u}=f^2 \mathbf{x}$ where I omit the dependence of $f$ on $\mathbf{x}$.

The differential writes
$d\mathbf{u} 
= 2f (df) \mathbf{x} + f^2 d\mathbf{x}$
where
$df
=(\nabla_\mathbf{x}f)^T d\mathbf{x}$

The Jacobian writes
$\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=
2f\  \mathbf{x}(\nabla_\mathbf{x}f)^T + f^2 \ \mathbf{I}$
and the divergence of $\mathbf{u}$ is the trace of this matrix
$$
\mathrm{div}(\mathbf{u})
= 
2f \ \mathbf{x}^T(\nabla_\mathbf{x}f)+ n\ f^2
$$